# Drop down menu positioning

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

so I'm having this issue. Here is the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/g5yo9jts/

```
<body>
<div class="header">  
<div class="menuIcon">   
  <a id="nav-toggle" href="#menuExpand"><span></span></a>
     <div class="box"><h3>Home</h3></div>
</div>  

<div class="menu">    
  <ul>      
    <li><a href="#">Menu Option 1</a></li>      
    <li><a href="#">Menu Option 2</a></li>      
    <li><a href="#">Menu Option 3</a></li>      
    <li><a href="#">Menu Option 4</a></li>    
  </ul>  
 </div>
</div>

</body>

* {
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
 }

#nav-toggle span {
margin-left: 15px; 
float: left;

}

 #nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 1px;
 height: 3px;
 width: 25px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 }
 #nav-toggle span:before {
 top: -6px;
 }
 #nav-toggle span:after {
 bottom: -6px; 
 }


#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
 top: 0;
 }
 #nav-toggle.active span:before {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
 #nav-toggle.active span:after {
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }

 h3 {
 font-size: 1em;
 color: white;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 font-family: "alternate-gothic-no-3-d";
 font-weight: 800;

  }



 .header .menu ul {
  padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 }

 .header .menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
  }
  .header .menuIcon {
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;

 }

 .header .menuIcon a {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
 }

 .header .menuIcon a img {
  vertical-align: middle;
 }



 @media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
 .menu {
 display: none;
 }

 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .header .menu {
 max-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s;
 transition: max-height 0.5s;
 }

 .header .menu.menuOpen {
 max-height: 1000px;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s;
 transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
 .header .menu ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
 }
 .header .menu ul li:hover {
  background: #999;
  }
.header .menu ul li a {
color: #fff;
text-shadow: #848484 0px 1px 2px;
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
}
.header .menuIcon {
 display: inline-block;
}
 }


 $(function() {    $("a[href=#menuExpand]").click(function(e) {                   
$(".menu").toggleClass("menuOpen");        e.preventDefault();    });});


document.querySelector( "#nav-toggle" ).addEventListener( "click",      
  function(){         

  this.classList.toggle( "active" );
 });


 $(".header").click(function() {
 $('.menu').show();

 });
```

The main issue is my hamburger icon and text font aren't lining up. As you can see the hamburger is centered vertically and the text is on bottom right. I've tried everything from margining the text, to adding a box div to the text to move it. Floating, absolute positioning is not working.

I'd also like to have the hamburger icon on the right, and the text for my page on the left but I was having issues with the centering that I hadn't got that far. If anybody could help out that would be awesome.

Thanks so much.

NB: Resize the fiddle 'Result' view to something closer to a mobile/tablet device display resolution to view the menu. Maximum width 767px.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't appear to be showing anything

Answer (score 0):

I think i have your problem solved. Only thing is there is a small gap between the header and the menu items when the menu appears (didn't tackle that) I'm sure some negative padding/margin will fix that right up

```js
$(function() {
  $("a[href=#menuExpand]").click(function(e) {
    $(".menu").toggleClass("menuOpen");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});


document.querySelector("#nav-toggle").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
});


$(".header").click(function() {
  $('.menu').show();

});
$(".swap").click(function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  var current = _this.attr("src");
  var swap = _this.attr("data-swap");
  _this.attr('src', swap).attr("data-swap", current);
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menuIcon a,
.menuIcon p {
  display: inline;
}
#nav-toggle span {
  margin-left: 15px;
  float: left;
}
#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 25px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
/*#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -6px;
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -6px; 
}*/

#nav-toggle img,
#nav-toggle img:before,
#nav-toggle img:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle.active img:before,
#nav-toggle.active img:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active img:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active img:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-family: "alternate-gothic-no-3-d";
  font-weight: 800;
}
.header .menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.header .menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
.header .menuIcon {
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
}
.header .menuIcon a {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}
.header .menuIcon a img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .header .menu {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
  .header .menu.menuOpen {
    max-height: 1000px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
  .header .menu ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    border-top: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
  }
  .header .menu ul li:hover {
    background: #999;
  }
  .header .menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: #848484 0px 1px 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .header .menuIcon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="menuIcon">
      <p>
        <h3>ELIJi</h3>
      </p>
      <a id="nav-toggle" href="#menuExpand">
        <img class="swap" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/hamburgerIcon.png" data-swap="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/close.png"></img>
      </a>

    </div>

    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Option 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Option 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Option 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Option 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```